# ARM template SQL Database - Configure managed identity for app (automated)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to automate the process of configure managed identity for app.
You can see on Microsoft documentation how to do it manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=sqldatabase%2Csystemassigned%2Cnetfx%2Cwindowsclient#code-try-8

But, I would like to have this in my ARM template.

Current issues:

- Only used from active directory can login in DB, I am not creating a login/password access;
- I tried to create an AzurePowerShell resource to create the user in DB, but I am passing my user and password (then cannot work in the pipeline), but even in this way I am having an error

"he provided script failed with the following error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open server xxxxx.com requested by the login.  The login failed"

```
{
              "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
              "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
              "name": "[concat('createServicePrincipalLogin-', variables('sqlDataBaseName'))]",
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', variables('sqlserverName'), variables('sqlDataBaseName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlserverName'))]"
              ],
              "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
              "properties": {
                "azPowerShellVersion": "7.4",
                "forceUpdateTag": "false",
                "timeout": "PT30M",
                "environmentVariables": [
                  {
                    "name": "SERVER_NAME",
                    "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlserverName')), '2014-04-01').fullyQualifiedDomainName]"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "DATABASE_NAME",
                    "value": "[variables('sqlDataBaseName')]"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "USER_NAME",
                    "value": "jorge.freitas@server.com"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "PASSWORD",
                    "secureValue": "mypassword"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "QUERY",
                    "value": "[format('IF NOT EXISTS (select dp.NAME from sys.database_principals dp WHERE dp.NAME = \"{0}\") CREATE USER [{0}] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;', variables('azureFunctionAppName'))]"
                  }
                ],
                "scriptContent": "


          $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
          $DeploymentScriptOutputs = @{}
          
          Install-Module SqlServer -scope CurrentUser -Force
         
          Import-Module -Name SqlServer

          Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ENV:SERVER_NAME `
                        -database $ENV:DATABASE_NAME `
                        -username $ENV:USER_NAME `
                        -password \"$ENV:PASSWORD\" `
                        -query $ENV:QUERY",
                "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
                "retentionInterval": "P1D"
              }
            }
```

Comment: is the script working if you run it locally ?

Comment: I would imagine you need to add some ip rules to bypass the firewall ?